# Mixpanel: Creating Complex Cohorts

Tags: mixpanel

I'm trying to create complex cohorts in Mixpanel. Here are some examples.

- **Active User Group**: Cannot be currently dormant (used once in last three weeks)
- **Dormant User Group**: Have not used Moonlight within the past three weeks
- **Engaged Users**: Active users who have at least 1 or more app session per week on average since downloading
- **Power Users**: Active users who have used Moonlight at least three times per week on average since downloading
  -** Dormant Power Users**: Users who fall into the power user criteria and are dormant (have not used app within last three weeks)
- **Dormant Engaged Power Users**: Users who are dormant but have at least 1 or more app session per week on average since downloading.

**Problem**: In Mixpanel, it seems like groups such as **Engaged Users** are difficult to make into cohorts because of aggregate conditions that apply to each user.

I was able to create these groups in Python by scraping data and wrangling it with pandas. I have lists of users in each group.

**Information I'm looking for:**

1. Is there a way to create cohorts for these more complex groups?
2. Can you upload a list or .csv file to Mixpanel and create a cohort that way?